# Avoiding running multiple queries by doing multiple joins, can't sepecity months

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm really stuck with this SQL. I have two MS Access Database tables setup as below:

**data** table

```
ID
UID
MYNAME
```

**monthdata** table

```
ID
DATAUID
MONTHVAL
VAL
```

I don't want to change this table structure. I have months and months worth of data in monthdata table which is associated to a reference in the data table.

I'm trying to end up returning three months worth of data in a *single query and a single row* like this:

```
UID - MONTHVAL - VAL - MONTHVAL - VAL - MONTHVAL - VAL
```

So if we wanted to get the last three months of data for UID ABC123 I was trying to run the following query:

```
SELECT data.uid, monthdata.monthval, monthdata.val
FROM data
LEFT JOIN monthdata ON data.UID = monthdata.dataUID AND monthdata.monthval = "01/09/2018"
LEFT JOIN monthdata ON data.UID = monthdata.dataUID AND monthdata.monthval = "01/08/2018"
LEFT JOIN monthdata ON data.UID = monthdata.dataUID AND monthdata.monthval = "01/07/2018"
WHERE UID = 'ABC123'
```

However it tells me that it is invalid syntax. However, despite my googling I can't find out how I can do it . The only alternative I can see is  to run three separate queries and put the date in the WHERE but in the real world example I have a lot more months.

Comment: Can't a cross tab query achieve this ? Or at least something very close?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a few issues with your query.  One is the lack of aliases.  The other is that MS Access requires lots of superfluous parentheses for joins:

```
SELECT d.uid, md_20180901.val, md_20180801.val, md_20180701.val
FROM ((data as d LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT md.*
        FROM monthdata md
        WHERE md.monthval = "01/09/2018"
       ) as md_20180901
       ON d.UID = md_20180901.dataUID
      ) LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT md.*
       FROM monthdata md
       WHERE md.monthval = "01/08/2018"
      ) as md_20180801
      ON d.UID = md_20180801.dataUID AND md_20180801.monthval = "01/08/2018"
     ) LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT md.*
      FROM monthdata md
      WHERE md.monthval = "01/07/2018"
     ) as md_20180701
     ON d.UID = md_20180701.dataUID AND md_20180701.monthval = "01/07/2018"
WHERE d.UID = "ABC123";
```

You can also express this using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT d.uid,
       MAX(IIF(md.monthval = "01/09/2018", val, NULL)) as mv_20180901,
       MAX(IIF(md.monthval = "01/08/2018", val, NULL)) as mv_20180801,
       MAX(IIF(md.monthval = "01/07/2018", val, NULL)) as mv_20180701
FROM data as d LEFT JOIN
     monthdata as md
     ON d.UID = md.dataUID 
WHERE d.UID = "ABC123"
GROUP BY d.UID;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. When I try to run this in access it gives me the error join expression not supported which seems to flag on this bit ```md_20180901.monthval = "01/09/2018"``` - any idea why this might be?

Comment: @Jimmy . . . Yet another limitation of MS Access.  I think subqueries fix that problem.  But the second method should work as well.

Comment: I'm really sorry about this but I'm having issues with both (same error on the second version of the first one). If I run the second I get ```The select statement includes a reserved word or an arguement name that is mispelled or missing, or the punctiation is incorrect. ```That error seems to point to ```mv_20180901.monthval```

Comment: Sorry! I can only say this code worked perfectly for me, the issue above was my mistake.

Comment: @Jimmy . . . 4 downvotes is definitely not you; just a bad day on Stack Overflow, I guess.  I can't figure out why.  I notice that an utterly inappropriate answer has been upvoted.

Comment: Well LOL. I got a downvote here (rightly so) and 2 on answers that had ~1000up / 0 downvotes until now.

Comment: @SalmanA . . . Definitely no reason for a downvote on your answer.  I was referring to the answer with `row_number()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it was posted (and perhaps upvoted) before OP specified that he was using ms access.

Answer (score 2):

When you join a table more times (like you do with `monthval`) you must use a different alias each time. Of course in this case changing the DB schema is something yuo should consider, anyway the syntax error comes from the missing alias, try this:

```
SELECT D.uid, M.monthval, M1.monthval, M2.monthval
FROM ((data AS D
LEFT JOIN monthdata AS M ON D.UID = M.dataUID AND M.monthval = #01/09/2018#)
LEFT JOIN monthdata AS M1 ON D.UID = M1.dataUID AND M1.monthval = #01/08/2018#) 
LEFT JOIN monthdata AS M2 ON D.UID = M2.dataUID AND M2.monthval = #01/07/2018#
WHERE UID = 'ABC123';
```

in the above i user three aliases form month data (`M`, `M1` and `M2`) and one for data (`D`), in the select I put `M1` and `M2`, but you can put the one you need.

Comment: When I try this (a cut this down a bit) and ended up with this ```SELECT D.uid, M1.monthval, M2.val
FROM data D
LEFT JOIN monthdata M ON D.UID = M.dataUID AND M.monthval = "01/01/2018"
WHERE UID = 'ABC123'``` but I get the error ```JOIN expression not supported```

Comment: you need brackets ON (D.UID = M.dataUID) AND (M.monthval = "01/01/2018"), i will edit my answer

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but I get the error syntax error missing operator in query expression

Comment: @LaBracca turns out it was only a matter of placing parenthesis in the right place.

Comment: @SalmanA that was my mistake because i typed the solution in stackoverflow and not in management studio and anyway i fixed parenthesis 2 hours before your edit, i do not understand your edit wtith # instead of " anyway i think i devoted even too much time to this answer that i will leave it

Comment: @LaBracca this question was specific to MS Access and, while your query was valid SQL, MS Access needed extra brackets (because it is stupid). Date literals in ms access need to be wrapped inside `#`. Doing both takes care of _JOIN expression not supported_ issue (but the OP has already figured out all of this in another question).

Answer (score 1):

Try below with row_number() and case when

```
    select uid, 
    max(case when  rn=1 then  monthval end) as month1, 
    max(case when  rn=1 then  val end) as val1,
    max(case when  rn=2 then  monthval end) as month2,
    max(case when  rn=2 then  val end) as val2,
    max(case when  rn=3 then  monthval end) as month3, 
    max(case when  rn=3 then  val end) as val3
    from
    (
      SELECT data.uid, monthdata.monthval, monthdata.val,row_number() over(order by uid) as rn FROM data
      LEFT JOIN monthdata ON data.UID = monthdata.dataUID and monthdata.monthval between '01/07/2018' and '01/09/2018'
WHERE UID = 'ABC123')a
      group by uid
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for this. I tried running this but get the error syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'row_number() over(order by uid)'

Comment: which db r u using?

Comment: Access database, sorry I should have mentioned